# Creating a home page using Root panel

Tags: java, gwt

I'm new to gwt and I want a page like this...

***********Header panel*************

Tab1 ***     Root panel 1

Tab2 ***

I managed to create everything but I don't know how to make my tabs vertical like that...

My code is,

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    headerRightPanel.add(portalLabel);
    //Tabs which I want it vertical
    headerRightPanel.add(orderMenu);
    headerRightPanel.add(homeMenu);
    headerRightPanel.add(logout);

    logout.addClickListener(this);
    homeMenu.addClickListener(this);
    orderMenu.addClickListener(this);

    headerPanel.setVisible(false);
    homeMenu.setStyleName("menuEnabled");
    orderMenu.setStyleName("menuEnabled");
    logout.setStyleName("menuEnabled");

    headerRightPanel.setStyleName("menuPanel");
    portalLabel.addStyleName("portalLabel");

    Image img = new Image("images/logo1.PNG");
    headerLeftPanel.add(img);
    headerLeftPanel.setStyleName("menuLeftPanel");
    headerPanel.add(headerLeftPanel);
    headerPanel.add(headerRightPanel);
    RootPanel.get("imageContainer").add(img1);
    RootPanel.get("sendButtonContainer").add(login);
    RootPanel.get("headerContainer").add(headerPanel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep elements in a vertical position, use VerticalPanel:

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/VerticalPanel.html

GWT has many components, unfortunatelly those ones are using tables, not css.

But in this example I would propably go with a css solution. And stay with divs only (FlowPanel with css class). GWT Vertical and Hirozontal Panels are using tables underneeth, that is a ... rough solution for creating layout.

I would mostly adise using UIBinder:

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html

If that is not too hard for you. But it would help you create a HTML fil next to java, and is more flexible when building complex structures.

Example: FlowPanel will produce a DIV in DOM, so you can add classes to it, set styles, css, hide it, show it, etc.

```
FlowPanel flowpanel = new FlowPanel();
flowpanel.addStyleName("css-name"); // yuo can add many css classes
flowpanel.hide().show()// you can hide and show it.
flowPanel.add(new FlowPanel())// you can add other elements to it.
```

Comment: Do you mean (Ordermenu,homemenu,logout)tabs in vertical panel?

Comment: Can you give me some examples for FlowPanel.

Comment: Put tabs inside a vertical/horizontal panel, that will set them in a certan position. All tab contents are by default hidden, so you will just have to on click show selected tab. Thats easy. I see only problem of tabs and content:) If there is something more, than tell me:)

Comment: I assume you understand that every GWT element renders a DOM element, so I would first create a target page in a plain HTML, and that element by element rebuild it using GWT.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole structure is wrong. Rootpanel is the parent layout to which you add other things such as panels and widgets. Are you looking for something like disclosure panel?

Here is the demo of all the panels and widgets in gwt
http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDisclosurePanel